# .Net Standard dependency for Nuget packages

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, .net-standard

### Current Situation

I'm having a .net core based project that target .net standard 2.0. In there I want to use the following Nuget package:

```
Microsoft.OneDriveSDK
```

Its dependencies are

```
Microsoft.OneDriveSDK
  Microsoft.Graph.Core
  Newtonsoft.Json
```

Looking into Nuget it seems that `Newtonsoft.Json` supports .net standard. `Microsoft.Graph.Core` does not list any target framework.

### Actual Question

Why does Visual Studio show a warning regarding incompatibility as shown below? To me it looks like all packages do support .net standard.

[image]

Comment: Graph.Core does not seem to target NET Standard 2.0, only .NET Framework 4.5 and .NET 1.1. It seems VS tries to use a shim to use the 4.5 version for your project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This warning is the result of the .NET Framework 4.6.1 compatibility of .NET Core / .NET Standard 2.0.

The warning tells you that it is using assets built for .NET Framework. This allows many libraries to be used in .NET Core 2.0 but also a lot of libraries may not work and throw exceptions at runtime (missing types / members, `PlatformNotSupportedException` etc.)

See the "Reusing an existing .NET Framework library" part of the [announcement blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/08/14/announcing-net-standard-2-0/).